# Is this undefined?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

My compiler warns: `operation on j may be undefined`

Here's the C code:

```
for(int j = 1; pattern[j] != '\0' && string[i] != '\0';){
    if(string[i+j] != pattern[j++]){//this is on the warning
        found = 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

Is that undefined?

Comment: Where is 'i' declared/initialized?

Comment: @MartinJames That's irrelevant.

Comment: You might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points?rq=1) an interesting read.

Comment: I think problem is related to [Sequence points](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sequence-points-in-c-set-1/)

Comment: @2013Asker Which compiler did you use ?

Comment: @Saradhi I'm using gcc

Comment: Usually when someone asks whether something is UB in C, it is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are these constructs undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-undefined-behavior)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**YES**. `string[i+j] != pattern[j++]` is having two different execution based on variable `j` without any [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) in between. So it is example of [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: The [page](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sequence-points-in-c-set-1/) you requested is _now available_ :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The C11 standard says in §6.5:

```
If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different 
side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the 
same scalar object, the behavior is undefined. If there are multiple allowable 
orderings of the subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such 
an unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.
```

Here, in the comparison

```
if(string[i+j] != pattern[j++])
```

you are both incrementing the value of `j` with `pattern [j++]`, and using the value of `j` in `string [i + j]`. The side effect of `j++` is not sequenced relative to the value computation `i + j`. So this is classic undefined behavior.